Replacing coil elements from hardwired to plug in
My parents have a 1961 electric cooktop with hardwired coil elements that have quit working properly. I can’t find hardwired elements. Is it possible to convert the connection to a plug-in for the elements. I have seen sets online with kits to replace the plug-in part. Will this work to convert this cooktop?

Depends where online.  Some online stores are known to sell electrical stuff that might be unsafe/untested.  Electric stoves use high power and high heat.  An older appliance repair person(maybe retired) will know how to do it safely.

as long the plug in is correct amps rated you can do it
